# Separate incoming content from a meta tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, meta

Okay I'm currently scraping a website by it's meta tag and getting a result back from it with this line of code:

```
 var affiliation = doc.getElementsByTagName('meta')[property='citation_author_institution'].content;
```

Now I wanna try to separate the incoming content by using ; in some way so I can easily divide the content.

I tried something like this:

```
 if (affiliation)
                    {
                            for (i=0; i<affiliations.length; i++)
                            {
                                    affiliation.push(affiliations[i].textContent)
                            }

                            item.extra = affiliation.join("; ");
                    }
```

extra is the field I wanna put it in, and I created an array so I can store all incoming content. But when I try this in my program I get an error saying something like:

"Type errorr: affiliation.join is not at function"

What can I do instead?

Comment: What is "citation_author_institution"? Does it exist on a meta tag like `<meta citation_author_institution="foo">`? If so, that's not how you filter for it. You can use `document.querySelectorAll("meta[citation_author_institution]")` to do something similar.

Comment: yea I get the content from that tag, that's not the problem. The problem is that there can be more then one line of content, so I have to divide them somehow.

So I wanna store it in a like string but where I use ; to divide them so I later on can easily use split to split the string.

Comment: `affiliation` is an array? If your first example is correct, it should be a string.

Comment: Okay I can show you what I have done and maybe you get an better picutre:

http://pastebin.com/zB8H3rP4

If you look where i wrote //affiliation.
I can get all content from that tag with the code I wrote. The problem is there can be more affiliations. And I need to seperate them somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by doing something like this instead:

```
for (i=0; i<affiliations.length; i++) {
    if (affiliations[i].getAttribute("name") == "citation_author_institution") {
        affiliationArr.push(affiliations[i].content);
    }
} 
item.extra = affiliationArr.join("; ");
```